# What limits are there on the number of reverse ssh tunnels?

Tags: ssh

We have 100+ embedded boards that we need to talk to occasionally.

We've found the best way to do this reliably (there are some strange internet connections out there) is to have the boards open a few reverse ssh tunnels to our server.

Currently each board opens three tunnels, for a total of around 300. The tunnels are inactive most of the time .

Are there any performance implications of this?  Assuming we don't run out of ports or file descriptors, what is most likely to trip us up?

**Edit:** I'm primarily concerned with having several hundred *inactive* clients connected at once.  Only a few of the tunnels will be in active use at any one time.

Comment: I'm curious about the need to open 3 tunnels per machine. Care to enlighten me?

Comment: One tunnel is for ssh, the other two are for services running on the clients that we need to connect to.  Currently we pull, rather than push data.

Comment: Just curious because I'd like to do the same - are you using some special software to manage all of this? Or do you open these tunnels manually?

Comment: Nothing very special, mainly bash scripts and monit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The limit on active SSH connections is 65,534 minus the number of TCP ports in use on your system -- If we want to be conservative let's just say 60,000 (or for most practical purposes "Unlimited"). You may bump up against *other* system resource limits however, depending on the machine you're connecting to.

That said you might want to economize on the number of tunnels (do you really need three connections per board?), and if you don't always need the connections up you might want to have the remote site initiate them only when needed.

Comment: It's the other system resource limits I'm interested in.  What might they be?

Comment: It's impossible to enumerate every system resource that can be exhausted - This is like asking for an exhaustive list of why a computer won't boot (the hardware fault tree alone would be a book). A few of them in rough order of likely exhaustion: max number of logins per user (if set), max number of logged-in users system-wide, max number of open filehandles, RAM, network bandwidth, CPU

Comment: I know - but first on the list are things like 'Is it plugged in?'  I didn't know about any logged-in user limit, so if I check that's ok I think we'll be good for a while.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR: memory. Rest is okay (for hundreds of tunnels).

> Assuming we don't run out of ports or file descriptors,
>   what is most likely to trip us up?

I think it is safe enough to answer: **memory**.

A quick experiment shows 4.6 megabytes of actual memory consumed per incoming connection. Part of it may be shared, a real experiment would tell. Fix: add swap space.

Also, 86 megabytes of addressing space which is quite big.  It's very probably shared, or a 32-bit server would have addressing space exhaustion before 50 connections. Fix: use a 64-bit OS.

> Assuming we don't run out of ports or file descriptors,

Does this assumption hold true?

- At the range of hundreds, **ports** won't be a problem, unless your server is also a high traffic server for something else.
- **File descriptors** might get exhausted. A quick experiment shows 21 file descriptors consumed per incoming ssh connection, not counting a shell. The limit on file descriptors can be tuned system-wide, so it should not be a real blocker.

(Experiments done on a 64-bit Debian server.)

Answer (score 0):

There are also systems that create the reverse tunnel on demand, when you need to connect to a particular remote computer. These include [AWS IoT Secure Tunelling](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/secure-tunneling.html) and [open-source software](https://github.com/sivantoledo/ssh-tunnels) that I wrote for the same purpose. These eliminate the concerns of having too many reverse tunnels simultaneously open.

My system uses MQTT connections (more specifically, AWS IoT Core, which is a secure MQTT broker with security policy for each client) to tell remote computers to open a reverse SSH tunnel to a proxy using a random port on the proxy. Once the tunnel is open, the remote computer reports back to your laptop/desktop the port number, and the software now establishes a tunnel through the proxy all the way to the remote computer; you do not need to log in to the proxy. Scalability is constrained by the number of active SSH connections to remote computers, not by the total number of remote computers that you can connect to.